# Tracking logged In Contacts in Sitecore 10

Tags: xdb, tracking

I am working on sitecore 10.1 project. We have login mechanism in our site so if user is logged in, we are identifying the contact based on the identifier(profile id of user).
If the contact does not exist, we are creating new contact and setting personal facets to it.
This works fine in normal scenarios.

The problem happens when, If I login in as user A(existing user), I get identified with an existing contact ID. Now I logout, and logs back in the same browser as user B(existing user), my code of line:

```
var identificationManager = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.IContactIdentificationManager>();
                            Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.IdentificationResult result = identificationManager.IdentifyAs(new Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.KnownContactIdentifier("IICMainWebsite",_profile.PersonId.ToString()));
```

takes too long to respond back, resulting in login process to delay.

My entire code is as below:

```
try
            {
                var identificationManager = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.IContactIdentificationManager>();
                Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.IdentificationResult result = identificationManager.IdentifyAs(new Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.KnownContactIdentifier("IICMainWebsite", _profile.PersonId.ToString()));
                var manager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager;
                if (manager != null)
                {
                    // Get contact from xConnect, update and save the facet
                    using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
                    {
                        var contact = client.Get<Contact>(new IdentifiedContactReference("IICMainWebsite",_profile.PersonId.ToString()), new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));
                        if (contact == null)
                        {                         
                      
                            Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
                            //Add identifier to contact.Person Id is used an unique identifier
                            manager.AddIdentifier(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId, new Analytics.Model.Entities.ContactIdentifier("IICMainWebsite",_profile.PersonId.ToString(), ContactIdentificationLevel.Known));
                            manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact);
                            // Now that the contact is saved, you can retrieve it using the tracker identifier
                            // NOTE: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource is marked internal in 9.0 Initial and cannot be used. If you are using 9.0 Initial, pass "xDB.Tracker" in as a string.
                            var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference("IICMainWebsite",_profile.PersonId.ToString());
                            // Get contact from xConnect, update and save the facet
                            contact = client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());
                            if (contact != null)
                            {
                                client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, new PersonalInformation()
                                {
                                    FirstName = _profile.FirstName,
                                    LastName = _profile.LastName// Replace with real input source
                                });
                                EmailAddressList emails = new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress(_profile.Email, true), "Preferred");
                                client.SetFacet<EmailAddressList>(contact, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey, emails);
                                client.Submit();
                            }
                        }
                        // Remove contact data from shared session state - contact will be re-loaded
                        // during subsequent request with updated facets
                        manager.RemoveFromSession(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
                        Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Contact = manager.LoadContact(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any suggestions how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How long is it taking?

Comment: It is taking 2-3 minutes

Comment: Is this an upgrade? Is user A a user with a lot of history (like a test user). What it seems like is it is taking a long time to load user A into the tracker. The only times I have seen this is for a user who has 100's of merged contacts.

Comment: Yes, it is for test users. I also think the issue is it is taking long time to load user A data in xdb. As I added code on logout to end the tracking and abandon user session on logout (Tracker.Current.EndVisit(true); HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();) It seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: clear  Contact on Logout, so when B user login the user gets identified as fast.